# How to change OpenSSH password in Windows Server

Tags: windows, openssh, windows-server-2019

I am very fresh with this and have never done this before.

I received a Windows Server 2019

Everything was working fine till I get a complaint from one user saying they cannot upload files to this server because of invalid password

in this server there is OpenSSH installed.

How can I change the password for the OpenSSH user?

Here is what I tried so far

```
mkpasswd -l [-u <username>] >> ..\etc\passwd
```

but what I got was

> 'mkpasswd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: The password to the user is to the Windows user. In other words, have them change their Windows password. If you don’t know how to do that ask your Windows Server Administrator for assistance

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, it worked, please put it as an answer I will mark it as the answer.
Thanks again

Comment: Btw, use SSH keys protected with passwords instead of passwords. They are much safier

Comment: @user996142 can you send me any link talks about this?

Comment: @asmgx sure: https://www.marksanborn.net/security/ssh-using-keys-instead-of-passwords/

Answer (score 0):

Just remotely access to the windows server and change the server password.

Ask your server provider from where you got the server aws, azure?

Here is the active windows topics https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues